# How to performance monitor an incoming PHP request?

Tags: php, apache

I've just migrated a new new server which in terms of hardware is significantly faster.

However, if I track a typical PHP request in Chrome (waiting for server to respond), I'm finding the response time is on average 20% slower.

I've placed timing code around the whole of my own code and I'm seeing an increase in performance of around 300% (which is expected).

So it's clear something else is taking up the time, but I don't know how to track it.

Can anyone point me the right direction?

Answer (score -1):

You can have a faster server but you could have latency issues as the new server might be further away from your location. Other latency issues can be because of the route your request takes to get to this new server and back. You should check only the code execution to asses the performance of the server. In the beginning of your handler function in the PHP script put a measurement. Put a microtime() in a variable in the first line of code and then put a microtime() after the execution at the end of the function before writing the response. Calculate the difference between these two points and log it to some file or put it in a custom header to the response. That should give you the execution time. Compare this to the old server by running the modified script in the old server and see the results.

To check network related issues you have to trace the route of the requests and the hops that request is making.

Comment: *I've placed timing code around the whole of my own code* sounds like they've tried that part.

Comment: right, I must have missed that part.

Comment: Thanks @AlbiPatozi as above, my own code is around 300% faster. I understand the number of variables involved in a http request is huge, it just that there must be a way to performance monitor it?